# Failure to transfer net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.44.0 and new version of TestNG. After executing a Maven build, an error is happening. This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>STTA</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the error:

> ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.15 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.15 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000

Comment: It's simply informing you that the location is not reachable by maven. Try downloading the dependency by hand or use the -U maven flag to force update. Delete all your .lastupdated file under your maven repository

Comment: The message says the connection to Maven central does not work. Network issues like behind a proxy etc. could be root cause which should be fixed first.

Answer (score -1):

add below dependency in pom.xml. It works

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for the above problem: connectivity to Maven Central. Forcing a different version of a dependency will not solve the connectivity problem, and could cause additional breakage in the user's project.

Comment: Using this solution problem is solved at my end. @SiKing better provide the solution